# Failure Symfony2 deployment to platform sh. SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002]

Tags: git, symfony, deployment, doctrine-orm, web-deployment

I have issue with upload Symfony2 project to platform.sh. I made everything step by step, according with symfony docs(I have created .platform.app.yaml, .platform/routes.yaml and .platform/services.yaml). But when I try to push everything to platform.sh master branch I have issue which I had described below.

```
 Generating runtime configuration.
  Found a `composer.json`, installing dependencies.

  Executing post-build hook...



      [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
      An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


      [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


      [PDOException]                             
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


  E: Unknown error in the toolstack: CalledProcessError: Command 'rm web/app_dev.php
  app/console --env=prod assetic:dump --no-debug
  ' returned non-zero exit status 1

E: Error building the project: Unable to build project, aborting deployment.
```

It is aborting everything. I have project which I developed for 3 months and I can't upload this anywhere... It is really confusing for me now.

I read, I should change parameters.yml, where are doctrine settings for DB. My file:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: '3306'
    database_name: yoda_event
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: ~
    mailer_user:     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    mailer_password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    locale: en
    secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
    use_assetic_controller: true
    assets_directory: 'assets'
```

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_platform.php }

[...]

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"
```

Question is, how can I made correct settings for SQL to deploy project to PLATFORM.SH correct? Please for any hints how can I solve that. I had tried to deploy it for two weeks now... I am completly lonely with it.

I am using win7/64bit, but when I will deploy it(at least) I will change system for linux.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue because twig was initialized and requested database to know which version of mysql was used. I solved this by adding the following under my doctrine configuration:

`doctrine:
    dbal:
        [...]
        charset:  UTF8
        server_version: 5.6`

Comment: Also fixes the issue for a Symfony 3 base. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
      An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Clearly, your app can't connect to database. You can try to replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` but I doubt it will help.

Anyway something is wrong with host you are connecting to: database may be down or absent, IP may be invalid, firewall may block the connection etc.